# LARAVEL: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having problems with a Issuecontroller. I try to dd() still Undefined offset Error when result exists, if there is empty data I access the pdf. what the problem of this code please help

```
 public function getReportPerPerson(Request $request)
{
    $u_id = $request->user_name;
    $req_id = DB::table('ssrareq_user')
        ->where('user_id', $u_id)
        ->pluck('req_id');

    $temp_particular_id = array();
    $temp_quantity_req = array();
    $temp_purpose = array();
    $temp_date_applied = array();
    $temp_quantity_issued = array();
    $temp_remarks = array();
    $temp_status_issue = array();
    $temp_status_req = array();
    $temp_item_name = array();
    $temp_unit = array();
    $temp_quantity =array();
    $temp_category =array();
    $temp_price = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($req_id); $i++) {
        $did = DB::table('ssrareqs')->select('particular_id', 'quantity_req',
            'purpose', 'date_applied', 'quantity_issued', 'remarks', 'status_issue', 'status_req')
            ->where('req_id', $req_id[$i])
            ->get();

        array_push($temp_particular_id,$did[0]->particular_id);
        array_push($temp_quantity_req,$did[0]->quantity_req);
        array_push($temp_purpose,$did[0]->purpose);
        array_push($temp_date_applied,$did[0]->date_applied);
        array_push($temp_quantity_issued,$did[0]->quantity_issued);
        array_push($temp_remarks,$did[0]->remarks);
        array_push($temp_status_issue,$did[0]->status_issue);
        array_push($temp_status_req,$did[0]->status_req);
    }

    for ($i =0; $i <count($req_id); $i++){
        $all_id = DB::table('particulars')->select('item_name','unit','quantity','category','price')
            ->where('particular_id',$temp_particular_id[$i])
            ->get();

        array_push($temp_item_name,$all_id[0]->item_name);
        array_push($temp_unit,$all_id[0]->unit);
        array_push($temp_quantity,$all_id[0]->quantity);
        array_push($temp_category,$all_id[0]->category);
        array_push($temp_price,$all_id[0]->price);
    }

    $row = array();
    $getinfo = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($req_id);$i++){
        $row['particular_id'] = $temp_particular_id[$i];
        $row['item_name'] = $temp_item_name[$i];
        $row['unit'] = $temp_unit[$i];
        $row['quantity'] = $temp_quantity[$i];
        $row['category']=$temp_category[$i];
        $row['price']=$temp_price[$i];
        $row['quantity_req']=$temp_quantity_req[$i];
        $row['quantity_issued']=$temp_quantity_issued[$i];
        $row['status_issue']=$temp_status_issue[$i];
        $row['status_req']=$temp_status_req[$i];
        $row['purpose']="nothing important";
        $row['remarks']=$temp_remarks[$i];
        $row['date_applied']=$temp_date_applied[$i];

        $getinfo[$i] =$row;
    }
    dd($getinfo);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.personal_result', ['getinfo' => $getinfo]);
    return $pdf->stream('personal_result.admin');
}
```

I try to dd still problem apper. but I encountered this issue too after turn off computer and turn on again

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is any result from queries. If there is no result, you can't access position 0. Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($req_id); $i++) {
    $did = DB::table('ssrareqs')->select('particular_id', 'quantity_req',
            'purpose', 'date_applied', 'quantity_issued', 'remarks', 'status_issue', 'status_req')
            ->where('req_id', $req_id[$i])
            ->first();

    if ($did) {
        array_push($temp_particular_id,$did->particular_id);
        array_push($temp_quantity_req,$did->quantity_req);
        array_push($temp_purpose,$did->purpose);
        array_push($temp_date_applied,$did->date_applied);
        array_push($temp_quantity_issued,$did->quantity_issued);
        array_push($temp_remarks,$did->remarks);
        array_push($temp_status_issue,$did->status_issue);
        array_push($temp_status_req,$did->status_req);
    }
}
```

Use this for both loops.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply still am getting the same error

Comment: not exactly but I changed database and everything works fine I didnt even understand what was the problem thanks

Comment: Ok! Good to know that!